# Hidden edges in Graphviz

Tags: graph, visualization, graphviz, neato

I'm trying to create a graph using Graphviz (complied with neato), and I would like to place nodes in specific locations. For this, I'm specifying exact edge lengths for all edges. However, I don't want all edges to be visible in the final image. 

Do you know of any way to hide edges? I should mention that I tried coloring the edges white, but what happens is that I get white lines painted over the graph nodes - it's not very aesthetic...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It can be done using

```
nodeA -> nodeB [style=invis]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that another way to go is to define:

```
outputorder="edgesfirst"
```

for the graph.

Comment: This is not an answer to the posted question, but rather: How to avoid edges over nodes.